# Convert hash keys into a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please review below input and helps me to convert it into the below output

Input:

```
arr = [{"Key1"=>1, "key3"=>1}, {"Key2"=>3, "Key4"=>0}, {"Key1"=>1, "Key4"=>1},
       {"Key2"=>3, "key3"=>0}, {"Key1"=>3, "Ke5"=>0}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{"Key1"=>1}, {"Key2"=>1}, {"Key3"=>3}, {"Key4"=>0}, {"Key1"=>1},
 {"Key4"=>1}, {"Key3"=>3}, {"Key2"=>0}, {"Key1"=>3}, {"Key5"=>0}]
```

Comment: In array we can flatten an array Like [[1,2],[3,4]].flatten => [1,2,3,4]. So like this I want to flatten my hash like [{key1: 1},{key2:3}]

Comment: You're probably using the wrong data structure here. Hashes are for storing *multiple* keys and values, if you just a single pair of values, use an array of two elements.

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far

Comment: I trust you approve of my edit. I did two things: reformatted so that readers do not have to scroll horizontally to read your question; and assigned a variable to your input object. You should always do the latter, as it allows readers to refer to the variable(s) in answers and comments without having to define it (them). Also, it's helpful for all readers to reference the same variable.

Comment: This is not a Rails question so you should remove the Rail's tag. The choice of tags can have consequences. Readers who filter-in Rails questions may be disappointed; readers who filter-out Rails questions may never see your question.

Comment: Also, can @RubyZeroRailsZero explain that desired output? I can see how they got some of those results, but not all of them (Specifically, where are `{"Key2" => 1}` and `{"Key2" => 0}` and both `{"Key3" => 3}` coming from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.flat_map(&:to_a).map { |k, v| {k => v} }
```

Comment: I need to sort them also.key which have max value comes first. Can you please help me

Comment: It will take 2 minutes to accept. I'll do. help me to sort the hash as required.

Comment: RubyZeroRailsZero, why the rush to accept any answer? There's no rush, Others may be working on answers right now.

Comment: Input: 
[{"key1"=>0},{"key2"=>1},{"key3"=>6},{"key3"=>1},{"key5"=>5}]
Output:
[{"key3"=>6},{"key5"=>5},{"key2"=>1},{"key3"=>1},{"key1"=>0}]

Comment: It was asking me for two minutes. I have forgot to taken a snapshop. Sorry, I have accepted your Answer. Thank you Much helpful. But can you please help me to sort the hash

Comment: @RubyZeroRailsZero If you want the results in a particular order, please clarify your question, or ask a new question.

Comment: When I left my comment  I had not noticed that you had asked the OP to select your answer. It's true that SO newbies may not know about accepting answers, but it's also true that if they are asked to select a particular answer they may well do that. You asking for the greenie, especially after such a short time, when yours is the only answer, is imo very bad form. If no selection has been made after several hours one might suggest the OP select the answer they found most helpful (if any were). I upvoted your answer, but would not have done so had I seen your request for the checkmark.